# onCreateContextMenu isn't being called

Tags: android, listactivity, contextmenu

It looks like the onCreateContextMenu insn't being called at all.  In my onCreate for my ListActivity I have:

```
list = getListView();
registerForContextMenu(list);
```

(I know it's redundant, and I've just passed getListView() with the same results).

Here is my onCreateOntextMenu;

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    Log.d("LM", "onCreateContextMenu");

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_landmarks, menu);
}
```

The log never gets generated.  Doesn't anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Just pass this along to others, I was also adding an onItemLongClickListener to the view.  It makes sense to me now why that's not going to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My thought is ListView intercepting the event and not going into contextMenu behaviour. It make sense to me because the OnItemLongClickListener behaviour overlaps contextMenu's. If not how it can recognize between contextMenu and OnItemLongClickListener?

Comment: That's what I found too.  After going back to the code to show that the long click was working, it struck me.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `youwidget.setonLongclicklistener` and `yourwidget.setLongClickable`

And then add `registerforContextmenu(yourwidget)` in `onCreate()`
then add code according to the widget used.

Hope It will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was very closely related to lulumeya's answer, which pointed me in the right direction. I've done context menus many times before and somehow never ran into this until now.

I was calling `View.setOnClickListener(listener)` in `Adapter.getView(...)` when it should be `ListView.setOnItemClickListener(listener)` to avoid conflicting with the context menu.

In general, I'm sure OnItemClickListener is more optimized, especially since only one listener instance is used instead of creating a new instance every time a view is created or recycled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate registerForContextMenu(list); as ur last method to call in the onCreate method.
I mean this method shoul be called after the list adapter is called not before.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem and could only resolve it by ensuring

1. that because the resp. Activity registered the Views, the same Activity must then also override onCreateContextMenu(); doing this in a Fragment will not work
2. since I used an additional Fragment creating the Adapter (and registering with it) the Fragment not the Activity must override onContextItemSelected().

I'm considering abandoning long press popup in favor of a Youtube-style button at the right margin of the cards popping up a menu that does not fade everything else to background---what's the search term for that btw?

Answer (score -1):

You have to call `registerForContextMenu(View view)` method in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.