# onCreateContextMenu is not being called

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-contextmenu

I am using the following code to generate `onCreateContextMenu`, however, I am not getting any response when clicking on a list item.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int currentId = (int) info.id;
    menu.add(0, MENU_DELETE_ID, 0, "Delete");
}
```

I will be using `currentId` later on, but the above code does not results in a popup with the word `Delete` in it.

Could it because I am using a custom `AdapterView` which is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41383203/4805990) to my previous question? Also, my `MainActivity` is extending `AppCompatActivity` if that matters.

I've checked other questions such as this one [onCreateContextMenu isn't being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057015/oncreatecontextmenu-isnt-being-called) but I am not using `onItemLongClickListener`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not enough code to understand what's actually wrong here. But I might suggest some frequent mistake to be taken care of while implementing the `ContextMenu`.

You need to register the context menu first. From the developers documentation of creating a context menu -

> If your activity uses a `ListView` or `GridView` and you want each item to
>   provide the same context menu, register all items for a context menu
>   by passing the `ListView` or `GridView` to `registerForContextMenu()`.

So you might consider doing something like this in your `onCreate` function of your `ListActivity`.

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

And I don't see any `MenuInflater` in your `onCreateContextMenu`. You need to inflate the view while creating the context menu.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

From the documentation

> `MenuInflater` allows you to inflate the context menu from a menu
>   resource. The callback method parameters include the `View` that the
>   user selected and a `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo` object that provides
>   additional information about the item selected. If your activity has
>   several views that each provide a different context menu, you might
>   use these parameters to determine which context menu to inflate.

And you might have to implement a long click listener for your list items. As it seems to work with long click events only.

> When the registered view receives a long-click event, the system calls
>   your `onCreateContextMenu()` method. This is where you define the menu
>   items, usually by inflating a menu resource.

Here you go for the full [implementation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu). Hope that helps!

**Update**

If you're not using `ListActivity` you should not be able to call `getListView`. In that case, just pass the `ListView` reference while registering your context menu for your list.

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

Comment: `getListView()` can only be used if your activity extends `ListAcitivty` if I'm not mistaken. So since I can't call it, that means I can't use `onCreateContextMenu()`?

Comment: Please see the updated answer and accept and upvote if helpful.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and helping with this.

Comment: Glad to know that helped.